# Summation Run Time algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm, runtime, analysis

I struggle with this problem. Previous problem I have done no problem. Now this one here is what I need to do.

I am trying to derive expressions for the runtime using summations.
Then solve them to obtain an expression for
T(n) or T(n,m) that not write with summation.
I want to count how many times the println is executed as a function of any variables n and/or m.

[image: I hope someone can help me out.! Thank You]

Any help will be helpful. What is the mathematic technique he talk about here? I search for and do more research if i know that

Comment: Use the given hint. This is by no means a hard question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the term "certain mathematical technique" is referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 0):

You have the following **while loop**:

```
int i = n;
while (i >= 1){
    System.out.println("tick");
    i = i/2;
}
```

We can rewrite this as a **for loop** as well like the example below:

```
int i;
for(i=n; i<= 1; i= i/2){
    System.out.println("tick");
}
```

Let's run through some iterations, we are going to give 'n' a value and see how many times the print statement is executed.

```
Value of 'n'   #Executions of the print statement   
n=1            1 
n=2            2
n=3            2
n=4            3
n=5            3
n=6            3
n=7            3
n=8            4
```

With the above we can get an idea of the number of times the print statement is executed. It looks like the number of executions increase when 'n' is a power of 2. So let's just see what the number of iterations look like for powers of two.

```
Value of 'n'    #Executions of the print statement
n=1             1
n=2             2
n=4             3
n=8             4
n=16            5
n=32            6
```

Okay we can now see another pattern as the power of 2 increases by 1 for example 2^1, 2^2 etc. The number of iterations increase by 1, so let's rewrite the above:

```
Value of 'n'   #Executions of the print statement
n=1 = 2^0      1
n=2 = 2^1      2
n=4 = 2^2      3
n=8 = 2^3      4
n=16 = 2^4     5
n=32 = 2^5     6
```

So it seems we can take the number two is raised to and just add one to get the number of times the print statement will be executed. For example, when n=32, we change this number to a power of 2 like 2^5, we then take the number that the '2' is raised which is '5' and add 1 to it 5+1 to get the number of iterations which is 6.

The function that can be used to solve this while loop is therefore:
**f(n) = (log<sub>2</sub>n) + 1**

You can also use summations to figure out a function for the **while loop**. 
You can see some [examples](https://youtu.be/essr83pAguU?list=PLj68PAxAKGoxhAXr-YyjeG9-SyTR5Hm4P) for changing loops to summations.